# How to create two columns and one of them shaped?

Tags: css

I need to create two columns. Variable-length text on the left and an image on the right.

[image: Example]

I tried clip-path but no luck.

Thank you
jval

Comment: Have you tried `skew`?

Comment: Yes, but need skewed only background.

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried as clip path should be able to do this OK and we might be able to spot what needs fixing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clip-path can do it. Here is an overview:

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  height: 300px;
}

.box div:first-child {
  background: blue;
  clip-path: polygon(0 50px, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 calc(100% + 50px)); 
  box-shadow:0 0 0 50px blue;
}

.box div:last-child {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```